# ¿En Python Pandas como puedo filtrar un dataFrame con parte del contenido de una cadena?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

Tengo un dataFrame que tiene una columna llamada `'linea'`. Quiero filtrar el dataFrame solo con los renglones que tienen la palabra `"GRANEL"` en su contenido y descartar todos los demás renglones. Para filtrar actualmente utilizo el código:

```
lista_produccion_terminado_granel = lista_produccion_terminado[(lista_produccion_terminado['linea']=='P3 EMB. A GRANEL')]
```

Pero este solamente me sirve si la cadena completa es igual. Si hay una celda que tiene el valor `"P1 EMB.A GRANEL"` ya no funciona.

¿Me podrían sugerir cómo filtrar el dataFrame utilizando parte de la cadena en la condición?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usa [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) para crear la máscara boleana con solo las filas que tengan la subcadena en esa columna. Un ejemplo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> data = {"col1": ("abcd efg", "granel", "ab granel cd", "afgdv", "ab GRANEL", "12458"),
            "col2": (45,45,89,23,55,77)}

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> filtro = df[df['col1'].str.contains("GRANEL", case=False)]
>>> filtro

           col1  col2
1        granel    45
2  ab granel cd    89
4     ab GRANEL    55
```

El argumento `case` indica si debe o no diferenciar entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Si solo quieres que valide "GRANEL" y no "granel", "Granel", etc basta con dejarlo darle valor de `True`.

Ten en cuenta que se usa el operador `in` de Python, por lo que "abcgraneldfg" sería también validada. Si esta posibilidad pudiera existir y solo quieres validar la palabra individual, debes usar una expresión regular:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> data = {"col1": ("¿GRANEL?", "GRANEL ABC", "GRANEL", "GRANELCD", "A GRANEL.", "12458"),
            "col2": (45,45,89,23,55,77)}

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> filtro = df[df['col1'].str.contains(r"\bGRANEL\b", regex=True)]
>>> filtro
         col1  col2
0    ¿GRANEL?    45
1  GRANEL ABC    45
2      GRANEL    89
4   A GRANEL.    55
```

Comment: Gracias, ya funcionó como me recomendaste. Saludos

Comment: Y para ignorar mayúsculas y minúsculas en el segundo caso, `flags=re.I`, con su respectivo `import re`, o agregando `(?i)` dentro de la expresión regular.

Comment: Gracias por las aportaciones, las tomaré en cuenta